# Excel Online: can users make their individual tabs in a worksheet read-only after editing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Is this scenario possible:

1. Admin creates a shared online worksheet with multiple tabs. Each tab is supposed to be edited by a specific person, but currently all tabs are accessible for writing to everyone so occasionally people mess up other people's tabs. That is, after UserA modifies TabA, UserB mistakenly edits TabA instead of editing TabB.
2. So instead, can any user make their tab read-only after editing? Not the whole worksheet, just a single tab. So at the end of the day, all tabs will be locked by different users (who are not admins).

Alternatively, can whoever creates the worksheet in the first place set individual passwords to tabs. Those passwords could be just the same as tab names (or something similar) and would be designed to make the user aware of which tab he/she is trying to edit. For example, UserB would have to enter "TabB" (or something similar) before editing the tab and would get an error if he/she tries to enter TabA.

Answer (score 1):

Excel online you'd better share different Workbook for Different users, according to your description, your needs are at risk in the same Workbook for different users.